# awk speed of substr function

Tags: performance, awk

(m)awk on ubuntu 20 is taking ++15 minute to process 500K lines of simple ascii text using the following awk code.  I don't see the hold-up in this highly simplified case. The eventual use case is to feed many files in, and generated many modified outputs files, thus FNR resets on each new input file, but that's not the issue here.

Suggestions warmly welcome:

```
#intended to be called from the command line with an -v argument

system("mkdir -p "output_directory)


# need a function to extract basename from filepath
# this exercise in parsimony works fine
function basename(file) {
    sub(".*/", "", file)
    return file
  }

{

#some vars.  
rec_code = substr($0,1,3)
first_letter = substr(rec_code,1,1)
first_two = substr(rec_code,1,2)

# This gets the data centre name for the output file. 

if(FNR ==1) data_centre = substr($0,4,5)
if(FNR ==1) outputfile = output_directory"/"data_centre"_"basename(FILENAME)
# now we parse the various input record types
#print(data_centre > clinic_id)

if(index(first_letter,"V") || index(first_letter, "M")  || index(rec_code, "C12")  || index(first_two, "S2")   || index(first_letter, "#") ) record = $0;

#S01

else 
     record = $0;

# S00 S02 S03 mods

# removed #TI for testing

}


{print record > outputfile}
```

The command line was: mawk -f test_10.awk -v output_directory=/home/rob/testoutawk2/ /home/rob/testoutawk/testdata.txt

testdata.txt is simple 50000 lines of 100 characters each of random text. Running time was 15 minutes, where as simple print($0) of the same file was < 1.2second.

I'd welcome suggestions on what on earth I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3):

The execution speed of `substr()` is not your issue, nor could it be or it'd affect all awk scripts. Your code will call `system()` once per input line for all files thus spawning 500,000 subshells. Don't do that, just call it once at the start of the script. It's also leaving all output files open and thus forcing awk to manage them, don't do that either, `close()` each as you're finished with it.

Change your code to something like this:

```
#intended to be called from the command line with an -v argument

BEGIN { system("mkdir -p \047" output_directory "\047") }

FNR == 1 {
    close(outputfile)
    # This gets the data centre name for the output file. 
    data_centre = substr($0,4,5)
    outputfile = output_directory "/" data_centre "_" basename(FILENAME)
}

{
    #some vars.  
    rec_code = substr($0,1,3)
    first_letter = substr(rec_code,1,1)
    first_two = substr(rec_code,1,2)

    # I assume you have some reason for this if-else so I just simplified the condition
    if ( (first_letter ~ /^[VM#]$/) || (rec_code == "C12") || (first_two == "S2") ) {
        record = $0
    }
    else {
        record = $0
    }

    print record > outputfile
}

# need a function to extract basename from filepath
# this exercise in parsimony works fine
function basename(file) {
    sub(".*/", "", file)
    return file
}
```